# How to set the from recipient in MessageUI using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using the below code. It's working fine and the email is sent successfully. But it takes my default login mail as the `from` address. How do I customize it?

```
- (IBAction)sendbutton:(id)sender {
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{

NSString *emailTitle = self.subjecttextfield.text;
NSString *messageBody = self.messagetext.text;
    NSString *recipents = self.totextfield.text;
NSMutableArray  * myarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",recipents,nil];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:myarray];

// Present mail view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}}
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller   didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The from address is the "default" mail account in settings. If you want to change it you must use a generic SMTP client library.